How can I customize the separator in the theorem heading of tcbtheorem?
I want to pass an optional argument in tcbtheorem, where a colon (:) usually appears before the optional argument.
Could you please help me achieve this?

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{titlecolor}{RGB}{24, 100, 140}

\usepackage[theorems]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\tikztriangletwo}{\tikz\draw[fill=white,draw=white] (0,0) -- (0.2,0.1) -- (0,0.2) -- cycle;\hspace{3pt}}
\NewTcbTheorem[number within=chapter]{satz}{\tikztriangletwo Satz} {
  boxrule=0pt,
  boxsep=2pt,
  before skip=10pt,
  after skip=10pt,
  colframe=white,
  sharp corners,
  colback=white,
  colbacktitle=titlecolor,
  fonttitle=\bfseries\color{white}\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont,
  description delimiters={}{}, % Removes the colon.
}{satz}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section One}

\begin{satz}{(Important)}{satz1}
    Hi I am satz one. 
\end{satz}
\end{document}


This may be unrelated, but I believe the minimum font size for standard classes like book is 10pt.

@EmanueleNardi Thank you for pointing that out! You're correct that the minimum font size for standard classes like book is 10pt. I appreciate the clarification!

I noticed it because of the warning: "Global options not used." Be mindful of warnings and always aim to work without them :)

description delimiters={}{} does not remove the colon; see page 378 of the manual.

The proper way to use it is: description delimiters={(}{)} and \begin{satz}{Important}{satz1}.

Could you update the question to specify what you expect the optional parameter to be and what the desired output is?

@EmanueleNardi Can I do optional argument unbold?

@EmanueleNardi Sure. Let me update the question.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

It is specified on page 379 of the tcolorbox manual:

/tcb/separator sign none: Sets /tcb/separator sign to empty

The key separator sign is also found on the same page:

/tcb/separator sign=⟨sign⟩: The given ⟨sign⟩ is used inside the title text of a theorem as separator between display name combined with number and the specific title text. It is omitted, if there is no specific title text.

Here you could pass your optional argument.
